# Possible to start workflow when item added to network folder?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, workflow-activity, csv

I am new to Sharepoint, but because I have development experience I am the 'Sharepoint Guy'. Sorry to all the professionals that I am giving a bad name, I am working on it - I swear!

We have a process that requires owners of Groups in Active Directory to approve all the members of the respective groups, twice a year. So far, our solution is a powershell script that reaches out to a text file listing the groups, and spits out a CSV with each group, group members and the owner of that group.

We'd like to be able to stick the .CSV in a network folder (shared library? not sure if that's right), have a workflow started that reads the contents, and sends emails to the owners of the groups so that they can approve (verify) their ownership, and that all members belong in the group.

Is this possible, or am I going about it the wrong way? I am awaiting formal Sharepoint training, so I have to teach myself in the interim.

We are using Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SharePoint!

I'd maybe have the PowerShell script write to SP instead of the CSV, listing the same details. From there the list via a workflow can email the owners. The owners can then come back in and 'approve' the item.

You could also do a timer job to perform the job the script does, so it's all in SP.

Comment: Up until this morning, I was unaware that Powershell had a CMDLet to do that. I spent the past few days getting the .CSV script fine tuned, but now that I know this is a possibility - moving forward - I will have to learn how to use this tool the right way for the job at hand. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Check out my post: http://davidlozzi.com/2012/02/29/loading-sharepoint-lists-from-excel/, this walks through reading a CSV and saving into SharePoint. In your case, your AD script will write directly to SharePoint.